# Limiting entry of "." and how many entries follow it

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently developing a UI for a till system.

How do I:

- Ensure that "." can only be entered once into a text field
- Ensure that only one value can be entered after the "."

Code below:

```
    private void AppendValue(string valueToAppend)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText(valueToAppend);
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText(valueToAppend);
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText(valueToAppend);
        }
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("1");
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("2");
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("3");
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("4");
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("5");
    }

    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("6");
    }

    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("7");
    }

    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("8");
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("9");
    }

    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue("0");
    }

    private void btndot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppendValue(".");
    }
```

Comment: Try [`string.IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx). @MUG4N that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some flags with global variables in your code.
Those flags should be cleared upon start of the input.
When you receive the character "." then you should check the flag in order to append it to the previous value.
Moreover when you receive the number you should check if a dot has been entered already and if yes if a number has been entered already ( you should use 2 flags ).

Or you could use one number saying how many digits after the dot you have entered.
Upon receiving for the fist time the "dot" you set that counter =1 . Upon receiving a digit, you check for that counter and if it is less than the maximum number of digits you need after the dot then you append it to the value and increment the counter by one.

The problem is that you need also to handle the backspace character in order to reverse your actions. So some care should be given and is better to act as bellow:

Use some flags with global variables in your code.
Those flags should be cleared upon start of the input.
When you receive the character "." then you should check the flag in order to append it to the previous value.
Moreover when you receive the number you should check if a dot has been entered already and if yes if a number has been entered already ( you should use 2 flags ).
Or you could use one number saying how many digits after the dot you have entered.
Upon receiving for the fist time the "dot" you set that counter =1 . Upon receiving a digit, you check for that counter and if it is less than the maximum number of digits you need after the dot then you append it to the value and increment the counter by one.

The problem is that you need also to handle the backspace character in order to reverse your actions. So some care should be given.

So you should get the new digit if it is backspace you should delete the last character from the string.
If it is numeric you create a new string with it and you check if that string is in the required format for you ( create a function with that scope only ).
If it isn't then you discard the new digit.
If the format is Ok then you accept it and append it back the the collected string.

Afterwards you use a function that checks if that possible output is what you accept.
If it is then you really append the character to the value. If not you discard the received event. That method allows also to receive the backspace character allowing to delete the last character form the text formed up to that moment.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered to passing value via sender and create just one event handler? for example?

```
public class MyForm : Form {
 bool DotAlreadyExists {
   get {
     return remainTxt.Contains("."); 
   }
 }
 void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var button (sender as Button); 
  if(button != null) {
    string toAppend = button.Text; 
    if(!String.Equals(toAppend, ".")) {
      AppendValue(toAppend);
    }
     else {
     if(!DotAlreadyExists) {
    AppendValue(toAppend);
 }

   }
  }
 }
}
```

I didn't try to run this code but I hope you feel the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

In actuality, the functionality you would expect from an EPOS system would be you entered `2` `0` `9` `9` and the screen would show **$20.99**. Or if you entered `1` `9` `9`, you would get **$1.99**

So a better method would be:

```
private void AppendValue(int valueToAppend)
{
    if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        remainTxt.Text = (Decimal.Parse(remainTxt.Text) * 10) + (valueToAppend / 100);
    }
    else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        totalTxt.Text = (Decimal.Parse(totalTxt.Text) * 10) + (valueToAppend / 100);
    }
    else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
    {
        paidTxt.Text = (Decimal.Parse(paidTxt.Text) * 10) + (valueToAppend / 100);
    }
}
```

This means you can do away with the `.` button. You can also create a `DEL` button that would turn **$11.99** into **$1.19**

```
 private decimal SubtractValue(decimal originalValue)
 {
      return Math.Floor(originalValue * 10) / 100;
 }
```

You would probably also want to use:

`Decimal.ToString("######0.00")` or `Decimal.ToString("c")` to ensure correct currency formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a bool variable:

```
bool dotControl = false;
```

And change it when dot appending:

```
private void btndot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!dotControl)
    {
       AppendValue(".");
       dotControl = true;
    }
}
```

Then to check the digits count after dot define another variable:

```
int count = 0;
```

And check it every button click:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dotControl && count == 0)
    {
       AppendValue("1");
       count++;
    } 

    else if(!dotControl) {  AppendValue("1"); }

}
```